# Ajax в WordPress вне functions.php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Есть ли возможность запустить Ajax, используя API WordPress, вне границ `functions.php`?

Я пытался сделать, но у меня ошибка. Переносил код обратно в functions.php и всё работает...

Смысл в том, чтобы на одной странице Ajax срабатывал, а на другой - нет. А так получается, что запрос к базе происходит каждый раз, когда пользователь ходит по сайту. Будет у меня, например, 20 Ajax и все 20 сработают, хотя потребности в них нет.

Пробовал ограничивать через проверку URL, но тогда Ajax вообще не работает...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете запускать скрипт только на нужных вам страницах. Делается это примерно таким кодом в functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );

function my_scripts() {
    if ( is_page( 'home' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', 'my-script.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
    }
}
```

На странице `home` ваш скрипт будет запущен, а на других - нет.

Прямой ответ на ваш вопрос - да, можно запустить ajax (имея ввиду php-обработчик) вне `functions.php`. Но только в тех файлах, которые загружаются при ajax. Это все файлы плагинов (и каждый более или менее сложный плагин использует ajax), файлы темы (начиная с functions.php). Но не шаблон вашей "текущей" страницы! Обработчик ajax-запроса в ядре WP ничего не знает о том, какая страница на экране у пользователя.

Поэтому ваши попытки вынести обработчик ajax вне functions.php не увенчались успехом.

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html вот инструкция. делайте по  ней. Не получится - создайте отдельный вопрос со своим кодом.